# Hover for single line

Tags: css, hover

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmxj2pLs/). The fiddle has 2 text (Read More) in a single line. I am wondering, how can I change the `Read More` text to:
`"Read" = Bold`
 `"More"=Italic`  on hover?.

At this moment, without hover it is `"Read" = regular`  `"More"=bold italic`

I do know that for hovering an element, the code should be like this:

```
p:hover {
  /* Write code here*/
}
```

But I am not sure how to apply the same hover to the above fiddle.

```html
<p class="readmore">READ <strong style="font-style:italic;font-weight:bold">MORE</strong></p>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is empty

Comment: @PaoloForgia Updated.

Comment: `p: hover strong { ... }` (You might want to remove the inline styles first for this to work.)

Comment: Don't make us visit jsFiddle for a [mcve]. That should be in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the `:hover` event to the parent class and then set a different style to each sub-class.

```css
.readmore:hover .bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.readmore:hover .italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p class="readmore"><span class="bold">READ</span> <span class="italic">MORE</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each word in a `span` tag and use `nth-child` to target them on hover:

```css
.readmore:hover span:nth-child(2){
  font-style: italic;
}
.readmore:hover span:nth-child(1){
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="readmore"><span>READ</span> <span>MORE</span></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vmxj2pLs/2/

Comment: This seems to be what he's asking, except the styles are backward.